# Can't switch columns in select of output

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

**I'm working on some problems on an open course-ware website that uses SQLite.
I have the following query and I am receiving the correct output, except when I try to switch

```
select all(maxi-mini) as spread, movieTitle
```

to

```
select movieTitle, all(maxi-mini) as spread
```

I receive a failed to execute error near all and have no idea why.
What am I not seeing?

*Working code, but can't flip columns in output.

```
select all(maxi-mini) as spread, movieTitle
from (select * from 
     (select max(R1.stars) as maxi, min(R2.stars) as mini, movie.title as movieTitle
     from rating R1, rating R2
     natural join movie
     where R1.mid=R2.mid group by movie.title))
 order by spread desc, movieTitle;
```

Comment: have you tried to omit the all-keyword (which is the default as far as I know)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the functionality of `ALL`.
`ALL`, the same way as `DISTINCT`, refers to the combination of all the fields in the SELECT clause and not to a specific field.
The brackets around `maxi-mini` makes no difference.
P.s. `ALL` is the default and you can really feel free to leave it out.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct

```
select all 

       maxi-mini as spread, movieTitle
```

Comment: That is correct Dudu Markovitz. Comment by Stephan Lechner was also correct. My problem was that I misunderstood the concept/uses of the "ALL" keyword